# Android Studio - test configuration starts up app

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-testing

I've got a couple of `AndroidTestCase` subclasses in separate packages of my project: 
[image]

However, whenever I run `Android Tests` configuration from Android Studio, I see that my regular app is starting as well. I see that the `onCreate` method is fired up inside my Application class (which is really bad since I am loading some additional resources there).[image]
 
Why is Android Studio/gradle running my app as well? 
 Can I programatically detect if I am inside test or regular configuration? 
 Can I stop my regular app from being booted before running tests?  
In addition, when I am running tests in debug mode it doesn't stop on breakpoints placed inside the application's `onCreate` method. Why is this happening?

**Edit:**

Body of test class doesn't really matter, it can be something like:

```
public class SimpleTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    public void testSample()
    {
        assertEquals(true, false);
    }
}
```

Executing only this simple test fires up `onCreate` method inside application class.
Gradle console prints out:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugTest]
```

I guess that first task creates instance of my `Application` class - is it expected behavior?

Comment: It would help to see the tests you are talking about. With the information you gave us I can just guess what might be wrong. And what do you exactly mean when you say "my regular app is starting as well"? And to debug a test you have to run the test in debug mode, just as if you wanted to debug an app.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - I've added some additional info. I was confused that my resources from onCreate method are still loaded up while executing tests, so I placed breakpoint inside this method and tried to run debug mode. Surprisingly, it didn't stop there. I could only be sure about that only by adding some logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is Android Studio/gradle running my app as well?
>
> Can I stop my regular app from being booted before running tests?

`AndroidTestCase` is extension of JUnit `TestCase` which is aware of your android application. In case you don't need to test your android application and want to test plain java only you should use JUnit framework. Create regular JUnit tests, do not use android classes there and run JUnit test configuration like this:

[image]

You should treat `AndroidTestCase` as instrumentation tests which will build android app and run that tests on it. This is usefull with combination of [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) and [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/). Both are working on top of base android test classes and both will build and run your application before testing it. Real device or emulator is needed.

Use plain JUnit tests or [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) to test java on your desktop JVM.

> Can I programatically detect if I am inside test or regular configuration?

You can use power of gradle to provide such info with autogenerated `BuildConfig` file.

At your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.foo.test"
    }
}
```

At your code:

```
BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME.equals("com.foo.test")
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on ' instrumentation tests which will build android app and run that tests on it'. Why it has to run the app after building it? And using your BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAM won't allow me to detect test configuration while checking it inside Application's onCreate method, right?

Comment: The instrumentation tests are meant for testing the UI. So the InstrumentationRunner starts the application, clicks on a text, checks if a view is visible etc. . You could describe it as a bot that uses the app to check if certain things work for your users. Therefore the app needs to run. For direct tests of your classes use Unittests instead. I think you should read something about unittests vs instrumentation tests

Comment: I thought Robotium and Espresso need the getActivity() method and therefore they depend on AndroidInstrumentationTestCase2 Class?

Comment: You can't simply make an instance of your `Activity` and test it. Because `onCreate`, `onResume` and others are not part of the java class constructor and are expected to be managed by android lifecycle system. In other words to create `Activity` instance you need to run application with it and trigger `Application` `onCreate` because it is called before any `Activity` method as part of android lifecycle. Move your logic out of base android classes like application, activity, fragment, etc. and test it via JUnit if you don't want to deal with application running.

Comment: @SergiiPechenizkyi actually I am not testing Activities and I have business logic kept out of them. I just need a Context instance to test stuff like database or some of the classes have to load resources from xml files. So it's not possible to test such classes (using Context) without running application before?

Comment: What is `Context`? It is basically your application, it contains access to your theme, assets, resources, strings, layouts, etc. How can android access them without construct application? If you want to test your database its needs to be constructed first, where should it be constructed without building your application first? Does it make sense? That's why `AndroidTestCase` is instrumentation test, when you need to build and test your application. 

You can mock `Context` and mock your database with mock frameworks like Mochito and Robolectric, then don't use `AndroidTestCase` facilities.

Answer (score 1):

The `AndroidTestCase` is an unit test that unfortunately runs on the device (either virtual or real).

I think what you want to have is a UnitTestFramework that runs in the JVM (local on your machine). The TestFramework [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org) can do this.

I have started a gitHub project to show how to setup the gradle test file and the project structure if you want to have UnitTests and InstrumentationTests side by side. If you want to look its [AndroidGradleTests](https://github.com/Dornathal/AndroidGradleTests)